# Jumping to code in variable memory in Windows

Tags: windows, x86-64

It possible to execute arbitrary machine code from a variable memory location in Windows? I don't really understand the memory layout of a windows program or if code and variable memory space is strictly divided..

Comment: You might want to read up on [W^X or DEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX)